# How to create a custom Material UI DataGrid column menu item?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, menu

For Material UI's DataGrid (v5.2.0), I am trying to create a custom column menu item to act on the column. If I set onClick={hideMenu} then the menu successfully hides when I click it. However, if I set onClick={handleMenuItemClick}, and in that function call hideMenu(), then I get an uncaught error, complaining about stopPropagation. This makes me think that I'm successfully accessing hideMenu() but the reference is wrong.

So my question is:

1. How do I correctly pass reference so that I can call/reference hideMenu and currentColumn?
2. (Extra Credit) Once I get that reference right, how do I mutate the data grid, such as deleting/adding/renaming columns?  Do I have to pass apiRef (eg useGridApiRef() ) or is the reference to currentColumn enough?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'stopPropagation')
> at index-esm.js:15:1
> at handleMenuItemClick (CustomColumnMenuComponent.jsx:17:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
> at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
> at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
> at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
> at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import {
  GridColumnMenuContainer,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';

export default function CustomColumnMenuComponent(props) {
  const { hideMenu, currentColumn, ...other } = props;

  const handleMenuItemClick = () => {
    // do something with currentColumn...
    hideMenu()
  };

  return (
    <GridColumnMenuContainer hideMenu={hideMenu} currentColumn={currentColumn} {...other}>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuItemClick} column={currentColumn}>Mutate Column</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={hideMenu} column={currentColumn}>Close Menu</MenuItem>
    </GridColumnMenuContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You must pass the the original event to hideMenu as an argument when wrapping it with a higher-order handler. The original event is supplied by MUI with onClick.

```
  const handleMenuItemClick = (event) => {
    // do something with currentColumn...
    hideMenu(event)
  };
```

The first example is working for you because the event passing happens automatically when hideMenu is supplied directly as the onClick handler.

Your second question is a little vague, maybe clarify exactly what you want to do. But in general, you can get access to the API methods inside your custom component like this:

```
const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
```

and the guide for using the api reference and the available methods are documented here
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/api-object/